# Should I use internal classes of an API in .NET when creating a Wrapper class?

Tags: c#, api, wrapper

I'm working in a project in .NET and part of it needs to communicate with a device connected through RS232 (com port) to the computer. I have received an API from the manufacturer of the device and it's written in C#.

I want to write a class library in c# and use it as a wrapper of this API in order to have all calls are centralized here and use only one instance of the API main class as it should be initialized only in the first call. (I think I must use Singleton)

The API has internal classes and enumerators, and some of its public methods request an internal class as a parameter.

My doubt is: Should I request the users of my wrapper those API internal classes as parameters or it's not a good practice to expose an API internal class outside the wrapper?

Also I'm doubting if it's a good idea to write that wrapper as the API is also written in C#, maybe I'm waisting my time?

Answer (score 3):

It *very* depends on how much time/resources you gonna to invest into this project, or you *can* invest in this project.

The absolutely good choice would be hide completely the internal `API` implementation from the consumer of you wrapper class. In this way, if you will get a new device, or a new driver for device (with a *slightly* different `API`), or completely new device with completely different `API` from different manufacturer, you will it again wrap into the **your** class, hiding all "low-level" implementation details from the user, which highly possible he doesn't care on..

But it **could** be a lot of work, depends on how big or good is written the original `API` of manufacturer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tigran. As far as I know, the API is not going to have mayor changes from the version I already have received. For example the API has a method  SENDPOSITION(GPSPosition position), should i ask the consumer of my wrapper to send a GPSPosition object to my function and then I send this to the API function? or should I hide this internal class?

Comment: @Frank_: Imo, it's better to hide it, but keep an eye on time you gonna spend on this

Answer (score 1):

Using a wrapper is a great idea, you're on the right track.
Wrapping will allow for code reuse, and as you mentioned you could create a singleton which will manage the object's lifetime.

About internal classes: Seems a very bad API if it exposes internal classes! This means you can't use those methods because you cannot create instances of those classes - nor will the consumer of your wrapper. 
So, if indeed this is the situation with this API, you should definitely hide this mishap instead of exposing it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jony, I made a mistake when I said "internal classes", what I meant was that they are inside the API (my fault, sorry). Those classes are public and I can instantiate them, so they could be used by the consumer of my wrapper. Having this, should I create the instances of the API classes inside my wrapper using parameters my consumer sent to me or should I allow them to instantiate API class and send it to my wrapper? Thanks!

Comment: My opinion is to take complete control of the wrapped API. If you are exposing everything, there would be no need for your wrapper, and worse - it would be used in so many different ways (through your wrapper and from within) and that will lead to code duplicates and less maintainable code. Limit the wrapper's interface only to what you need in your application and expose more if and when necessary.